# How to fix Serverless error "Invalid API Key identifier specified" when using 2 stages with api keys on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am using the following configuration to deploy a couple lambda functions to different stages `prod` and `dev` on AWS. Both stages should be protected with an api key which is stored in SSM.

**serverless.yml**

```
service: my-service
frameworkVersion: "3"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  region: eu-central-1
  apiGateway:
    apiKeys:
      - name: my-apikey
        value: ${ssm:my-apikey}

functions:
  v1_myfunc:
    handler: src/api/myfunc/get_func.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: /v1/myfunc
          method: get
          private: true

plugins:
  - serverless-esbuild
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
```

My deployment scripts look like this:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "deploy:dev": "serverless deploy --stage dev",
  "deploy:prod": "serverless deploy --stage prod"
}
```

**The problem:**

When I deploy one of the stages then everything works fine. But if I deploy the other one afterwards, I always get the following error (in this case I deployed prod first, and then dev):

```
Deploying my-service to stage dev (eu-central-1)

✖ Stack my-service-dev failed to deploy (46s)
Environment: darwin, node 16.15.0, framework 3.23.0, plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Credentials: Local, "default" profile

Error:
Invalid API Key identifier specified
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Looking into AWS console, I noticed that the generated api key **has the same id** for both stacks (dev and prod). So, I'm guessing this is where the problem is: Both stacks sharing the same api key instance.

So, I tried to fix this by setting different api key names for each stage:

```
- name: my-apikey-${self:provider.stage}
  value: ${ssm:my-apikey}
```

But this doesn't solve the problem, as I'm still getting this error:

```
Invalid API Key identifier specified
```

**Question:** How do I have to change my `serverless.yml` config to fix the issue?

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/5246

Comment: Let me do some reading as it's an odd issue, I think you could probably use a config map - but let me check before I post an answer :-)

Comment: Could you also post your full serverless.yml please if possible?

Comment: @MrkFldig Thanks for your reply. I'll give you suggestion a shot and will get back if it worked or not.

Comment: @MrkFldig The serverless.yml I posted in my original question is actually complete. Only thing I changed is that I replaced my lambda function name with myfunc and removed the other functions.

Comment: Great, I am at keys today so can work through it if that doesn't work, I have a hunch it's the state from the previous deployment in .serverless that's causing it.

Comment: @MrkFldig What if I did a `rm -Rf .serverless` before each deployment. Would that cause a problem?

Comment: I need to check that actually, I'm about to do a load of updates for one of our serverless api's I think it works on stack name so you wouldn't get a new apig URL between deploys like that. In fact if you add service: my-service-${sls:stage) it might work, give me a short while I'll test it!

Comment: In reality though you wouldn't normally do an sls deploy with the same .serverless dir on a real world app being deployed by CI(Github actions, circle etc)

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/in/marc-fielding/ that's me on LinkedIn if you want to chat about it rather than loads of comments :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api key **values** for both stages need to be different:

```
service: my-service
frameworkVersion: "3"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  region: eu-central-1
  apiGateway:
    apiKeys:
      ${self:custom.apiTest.${sls:stage}}
functions:
  v1_myfunc:
    handler: src/api/myfunc/get_func.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: /v1/myfunc
          method: get
          private: true

plugins:
 - serverless-esbuild
 - serverless-offline
 - serverless-dotenv-plugin

custom:
  apiTest:
    dev: 
      - name: api-key-dev
        value: 123 # Needs to be different vs prod!
    prod: 
      - name: api-key-prod
        value: 456 # Needs to be different vs dev!
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but now I am getting this: `UPDATE_FAILED: ApiGatewayApiKey1 (AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey)
Resource handler returned message: "API Key already exists (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 409, Request ID: 123)" (RequestToken: 456, HandlerErrorCode: AlreadyExists)`

Comment: There is also another thing I noticed: If I check for the dev api key in AWS console, then I noticed that API Gateway is using the PROD usage plan for the DEV api key 

Comment: Oh and seems like after the change you suggested, my local serverless offline config doesn't work any more, as I'm getting `provider.apiGateway.apiKeys` when calling `serverless offline --stage local --noPrependStageInUrl --noAuth --reloadHandler`

Comment: Well I suck then don't I lol, just eating some lunch and I'll grab yml with my own code and have a fiddle, it being friday it's an easy day

Comment: Err first thing --stage should equate to the map at the bottom so needs to be dev or prod.

Comment: Well I got my local server running again by simply adding a local custom name/value keypair to `apiTest`.

Comment: Trying to deploy to AWS with `yarn deploy:dev` still gives me `Invalid API Key identifier specified` because all the change in serverless.yml did was to change the name of the api key but that won't help because both stages, prod and dev, are referencing the exact same api key id and using the same usage plan.

Comment: Correction: The error message was `API Key already exists`

Comment: Oh, hold on! I finally solved it!!  The solution was that I had to use 2 different values for the api key for each stage. Using just different names wasn't enough.

Comment: Nice, sorry busy weekend glad you got it sorted, yeah tis why I put //value for prod / // value for dev :-)

Comment: Thanks for your support. If you want, feel free to edit your answer and I'll be happy to accept it as the correct answer. I think the only change needed is to point out that different values for the api key are required. Other then that I'm pretty much using the same code you posted.

Comment: Sure will do! Thanks Timo.

Comment: I edited for you and accepted the answer . Feel free to change anything you dislike about my edit.

Comment: Thanks Timo, sorry busy week I hadn't been paying attention.